# how to read data from rs232 ??( TES-1370)

Tags: pi-3

I have a thermo-hydro-ndir co2 meter (TES-1370)
and I want to read data from it
but I don't know how to use it by RS232
how would I suppose to do??

thanks for your answers!!!

Comment: Welcome! This site is for raspberry pi specific questions and your question appears to be more generic in nature. If you are facing any specific problems interfacing the device with the raspberry pi, please add more details on what you have done/have setup and what is not working. I'd recommend looking at the sister websites stackoverflow.com for software related questions and electronics.stackexchange.com for more hardware related ones.

Comment: Not to leave you disappointed, looking at the manual [here](http://www.mrclab.com/data/products/TES-1370A_OPR.pdf) the last page indicates the device comes with a cd-rom with the required rs232 protocol details. Recommend looking through that to get started. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To set serial port at 9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, enable hardware handshaking, translate newline to carraige return, icanon receive chars without line feed, xon/xoff disable, disable echo to serial port 1

```
stty 9600 cs8 -parenb crtscts -onlcr -icanon -ixon -echo -F /dev/ttySAC1
```

To read the serial port receive data

```
cat < /dev/ttySAC1 &
```