# Read data from RS232

Tags: python

I'm new to pi and Python.

I have pi3 and a meter([Tes-1370](http://www.gunyuz.com/dosyalar/1370-e03_456.pdf)),

I want to read the data from meter

and meter read data by RS232

but pi don't have RS232

so , I buy a RS232-USB adapter , USB connect to pi3

and I use Python3 and PySerial to read that

but get some problem
this is my code

```py
import serial

port =serial.Serial(

      "/dev/ttyUSB0",
      baudrate=9600,
      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
      writeTimeout = 0,
      timeout = 10)

print(port.isOpen()) 

print("Port opened...")

while True:

     print("inside while")
     response=port.read(8)
     print(response)
     print ("Data Received")
```

but it print

b'\x1c\xb7\x04\x88f\x1c\xb7\x04

I don't know what it is

can anyone help me??

Comment: I see you have posted the same/similar question you had asked [just a day](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/how-to-read-data-from-rs232-tes-1370?s=1|2.9886) earlier. I had indicated in my comment on that question, that the protocol appears to documented only within the contents of the CD rom and doesnt appear to not publicly available despite my google-foo. If you could share the contents or details on the CD, you might find more assistance from more folks here. Any case you don't have a CD with you, you'll probably need to reach out to the manufacturer to get a copy.

Comment: appreciate for your answer!!
and this is protocol in the CD!!

[protocol](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byc5d17kyECudGF5VTRkekp5ZHc)

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the attached CD-ROM.

From the linked PDF.

> VIII. RS-232 INTERFACE, SOFTWARE INSTALLATION and OPERATION
>
> For  the  detailed  instruction,  please  refer  to  the  content  of
>   attached  CD-ROM,  which  has  the  complete  instruction  of RS-232
>   interface,     software     operation     and     relevant
>   information.
>
> RS-232 protocol : are enclosed within the content of CD-ROM, please
>   open the CD-ROM for details.

Comment: thank you for your answer!!
I found the CD and I put on this [protocol](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byc5d17kyECudGF5VTRkekp5ZHc)